# Active/Passive FTP Transfer using FTPWebrequestclass

Tags: ftp, ftpwebrequest

I am transferring files using `FtpWebRequest` class in C#; in that class there is a property

```
ftpobject.usePassive = true (or) false;
```

I meant it as

- if use passive is false then it is "Active"
- if use Passive is true then it is "Passive"

what i meant above is right or wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're right. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.usepassive.aspx):

> false if the client application's data transfer process listens for a connection on the data port; otherwise, true if the client should initiate a connection on the data port. The default value is true.

...and...

> Setting the UsePassive property to true sends the "PASV" command to the server. This command requests the server to listen on a data port and to wait for a connection rather than initiate one upon receipt of a transfer command.